# Deploying typeorm/typescript app on heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, heroku, typeorm

I'm having a problem with deploying typeorm app on heroku. Here's the completely minimalistic version of this app:
https://github.com/wiktorkujawa/typeorm-heroku

So what I've done:

1. Started project
   typeorm init --name typeorm-heroku --database postgres

---

### Server(typeorm-postrges folder)

2. In server folder(cd typeorm-postgres) typed:
   npx tsconfig.json( choose for example node)
   created yarn.lock file and updated it ...

Installed dependencies for server.

### Simple connection in index.tsx
Added Procfile file(which changed nothing)

### Client

1. Created react project and install dependencies for them:
   npx create-react-app web --typescript
   yarn add ...
   2.Create graphql folder inside src folder and initialize graphql code generator
   npx graphql-codegen init

   Where is your schema?: http://localhost:4000/graphql
   Where are your operations and fragments?:
   src/graphql/*.graphql
   Where to write output: (let it be default)
   ...(default)
   What script in package.json should run the codegen? gen

In codegen.yml added:

```
config:
       hooksImportFrom: '@apollo/react-hooks'
       withHooks: true
       withHOC: false
       withComponent: false
```

and installed dependencies of codegen with:
yarn
3. generate schemas:
yarn gen
4. In index.tsx copied code from https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/migrating/boost-migration/#advanced-migration

5. Read simple list query to check if queries works, but it only works in dev mode.
   In heroku I get big heroku page with this:

> Application error
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the
> application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the
> command
> heroku logs --tail

Here's the error after typing heroku logs --tail in terminal:

```
2020-06-28T18:40:57.079023+00:00 app[web.1]: > typeorm-heroku@0.0.1 start /app
2020-06-28T18:40:57.079024+00:00 app[web.1]: > ts-node src/index.ts
2020-06-28T18:40:57.079024+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-28T18:40:57.085699+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: ts-node: not found
2020-06-28T18:40:57.095880+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-06-28T18:40:57.096505+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-06-28T18:40:57.097800+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-06-28T18:40:57.098220+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-06-28T18:40:57.099843+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! typeorm-heroku@0.0.1 start: `ts-node src/index.ts`
2020-06-28T18:40:57.100130+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-06-28T18:40:57.100384+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-06-28T18:40:57.100546+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the typeorm-heroku@0.0.1 start script.
2020-06-28T18:40:57.100713+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-06-28T18:40:57.119552+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-28T18:40:57.120040+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-06-28T18:40:57.120170+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-06-28T18_40_57_105Z-debug.log
2020-06-28T18:40:57.195532+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-28T18:40:57.257902+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-28T18:41:03.656226+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=typeorm-heroku.herokuapp.com request_id=4e810375-5365-47c5-bccd-a6b28a893359 fwd="178.235.225.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-28T18:41:04.010781+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=typeorm-heroku.herokuapp.com request_id=1a30a549-55a7-49af-a6b5-f199ee78fda0 fwd="178.235.225.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Well, I think that the problem is in package.json, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: what is in `/app/.npm/_logs/2020-06-28T18_40_57_105Z-debug.log`?

Comment: Well, I don't know, but I found the solution. I had to install ts-node as dependencies(not as devDependencies like it was before).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to install ts-node in dependencies( not devDependencies).

Answer (score 1):

What is your node package version you can check it by typing `npm -v` if it's new like v12.xx try to downgrade to v10.16 and change it in the package.json

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` to reinstall all the project dependencies

Comment: Not working(well, I knot that this will not work, because I did it before about 10 times with different packages), but to be sure I did it again.

Answer (score 0):

Use docker to deploy the backend server to heroku. And deploy the frontend on vercel. This is how I usually deploy typescript app. You can setup docker server as given in https://github.com/benawad/lireddit/blob/master/server/Dockerfile